# Do the glowing pillars in The Storm Halls do anything?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that occasionally if I shoot at (or near) the glowing red pillars they will kind of explode a bit for a second and then reform. Does this affect my attacks in any way? What about nearby enemies? Is this purely cosmetic (like pillars in other dungeons crashing down)?
[image: Rest state for pillar]
[image: Excited state for pillar]

Comment: As far as I can tell they seem to be added for effect. No real purpose.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen gold rarely drop from them, but not sure enough to put it to an answer. It may have easily been something else too, I really wasn't watching at the time.

Comment: I destroyed every one that I came across (normal mode) and nothing happend, not once.  No gold, didn't notice any change in stats, and no (noticable) dmg to enemies.  I doubt it changes for the other difficulties, but as I haven't gotten that far, can't say one way or the other.

Comment: Wait, you can destroy these pillars?

Comment: As a barbarian, they can be useful for generating fury. Hitting them will generate fury just like hitting a mob or a crate.

Comment: @shadowfission I'd consider that an answer if you want to make it one!

Comment: @shadowfission: Nice info, seems to be the only good ingame use for them - suggest posting that as an answer.

Comment: Don't they also count towards the "destroyed X objects" bonus exp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They'll continue to animate as long as you switch between the two targets; there are usually two of them near each other. When you hit one, it will animate but won't animate again until the other is hit. Besides that, I personally have not found any other use for them and I also have not heard any other use from anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

The pillars just appear to be aesthetic with no real function. There seems to be no direct method of interacting with them but as you mention at times when you fire towards them they animate.